# Getting type of file request

Tags: php, types, request

I have this example code:

```
<img src="e.php"/>
<link href="e.php" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="e.php"></script>
```

Is there a way to know if *e.php* is loaded on the window or if it is called by those document elements?

Comment: `jQuery.load` will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request is 'friendly' - i.e. you can trust it - simply pass a parameter from inside your DOM:

```
<img src="e.php?query=DOM"/>
```

otherwise, if you can not trust this (i.e. parameters will be changed) - there's no way to figure out type of query - it can be either 'normal', query from elements or even via [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) call (in common case, cURL is a [third-party library](http://curl.haxx.se/))

Comment: But I don't know what do you mean with the use of cURL

Comment: @SergiFrom - ok, I've edited. That is only a sample for you to realize that in common case there are many ways to perform HTTP-query to your script, so it's impossible to differ two cases (DOM & 'normal') if the client will provide fake information in query.

Comment: Okey, using query string to differ is not viable on my proyect. I'll search another way to solution my problem, but in another question not related to this one.